# Problema para criação de uma lista ligada em C

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

Olá, estou tentando criar uma lista ligada de forma automática, ou seja, ela será criada dentro de um `for`. Porém por alguma razão fico recebendo o erro segmentation fault, segue o código:

```
no *lista, *cabeca;
  int n, r1, *r2;
  int i,j;
  cabeca = malloc(sizeof(no));
  cabeca->prox = NULL;
  cabeca = lista;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    lista = malloc(sizeof(no));
    lista->valor = n-i;
    lista->prox = cabeca->prox;
    cabeca->prox = lista;
  }
//esse scanf será outra funcao do meu codigo
  scanf("%d", &r1);
  r2 = malloc(r1*sizeof(int));
  for(j = 0; j < r1; j++){
    scanf("%d ", &r2[j]);
  }
```

Comment: edite sua pergunta formatando o código...no menu da janela de edição tem um ícone de abre/fecha chave...selecione as linhas de código com o mouse e clique no ícone abre/fecha chave, senão seu código fica ilegível

Answer (score 1):

Vejamos o seu código o que faz. Primeiro temos isso:

```
no *lista, *cabeca;
```

Nessa linha acima, você declara os ponteiros `lista` e `cabeca`, não inicializados. Depois, temos isso:

```
cabeca = malloc(sizeof(no));
cabeca->prox = NULL;
```

Aqui, você faz `cabeca` apontar para uma região de memória alocada para guardar um nó e define o próximo nó como sendo `NULL`, para não deixar o ponteiro não-inicializado. Entretanto, a referência `cabeca->valor` continua não inicializada.

Em seguida temos isso:

```
cabeca = lista;
```

**OPS!** Aqui você está colocando em `cabeca` o conteúdo de um ponteiro não-inicializado. Como a referência antiga é perdida, também temos um vazamento de memória.

Já dentro do `for`, temos isso:

```
lista = malloc(sizeof(no));
lista->valor = n-i;
```

Está criando um novo nó e colocando na variável `cabeca`. Tudo bem ainda.

Logo em seguida:

```
lista->prox = cabeca->prox;
```

Lembra que `cabeca` era um ponteiro não inicializado? Pois é, isso significa que `cabeca->prox` vai dar uma falha de segmentação!

Em seguida:

```
cabeca->prox = lista;
```

Se isso chegasse a executar, seria outra falha de segmentação.

Por fim, esse último trecho, acho que está correto:

```
scanf("%d", &r1);
r2 = malloc(r1*sizeof(int));
for(j = 0; j < r1; j++){
  scanf("%d ", &r2[j]);
}
```

Acho que o que você queria era isso:

```
no *lista = NULL, *cabeca = NULL;
int i, j, n, r1, *r2;
scanf("%d", &n);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    lista = malloc(sizeof(no));
    lista->valor = n - i;
    lista->prox = cabeca;
    cabeca = lista;
}
scanf("%d", &r1);
r2 = malloc(r1 * sizeof(int));
for (j = 0; j < r1; j++) {
    scanf("%d ", &r2[j]);
}
```